# Capturing checking piece (chess)

Tags: chess

Was playing some chess.com and found this position where the recommended best move is black Kb7. When I tried to play manually and play black pawn captures d8, it won't let me. Can you not promote a pawn by capturing?[image: position]

Answer (score 8):

Based on the row numbers shown, this board is from white's perspective; the black pawn is still in its starting position. Pawns cannot move or capture backwards, in order to promote a black pawn you must move it all the way to row 1, not row 8.

Comment: Algebraic notation is _always_ from white's perspective isn't it? i.e. white starts on ranks 1 and 2, black on ranks 7 and 8.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The rank numbers are always such that Black promotes on Rank 1. However, the board is often shown such that the player promotes on the top of the board (so if you're playing Black, Rank 1 is on the top of the board). While this board does have the ranks numbered, they aren't as obvious as the board orientation.